# How to print the string "\n"

Tags: python

I want to print the actual following string: `\n` , but everything I tried just reads it in takes it as a new line operator.. how do I just print the following: `\n` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
print "\\n"
```

or a raw string

```
print r"\n"
```

Have a look at the tutorial concerning [strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `\` with another `\`.

```
print "\\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape `\n` somehow

Either just the sequence

`print  "\\n"`

or mark whole string as raw

`print r"\n"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
>>> print("\\n")
\n
```